# SharePoint 2010 Password Change?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, password-management

Does anyone know of a way to allow password changes via SharePoint's web interface?  Either a add on or settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this web part: http://changepassword.codeplex.com/

Works on 2010: http://changepassword.codeplex.com/discussions/219795

Comment: Do you also have a guide for the installation of this?  As I've tried it via power shell Add-SPSolution etc, however this still isn't working?

Comment: Add it to the solution store with `stsadm -o addsolution -filename ItacsChangePassword.wsp`

Comment: Then deploy it right...?

Comment: Yes <!-- Ugh, Comment min length -->

Comment: Thank you.  Wil give this a shot when I'm back in work tomorrow.